# having an issue passing data between pages in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I've been doing a tutorial on passing data in flutter, and I am pretty much using the tutorials code 
this is the class that I want the parameter to be accessible on

```
class handler extends StatefulWidget {
     handler({this.value});
    final String value;
    _handler createState() => _handler();
```

}

So value should be an accessible parameter to use on another page of code but when I try to access it with this

```
var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
            new handler(value:pat),
          );
```

The ide says that the parameter "value" is not defined

Comment: try this command : flutter clean ,  don't forget to save the file, sometimes we forget to save after any change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution what you have to do is place the value in the stateless widget as an optional key, and then in the state make it a mandatory variable then use the optional call from the stateless widget to fill in the mandatory parameter.

Comment: or you can just reference it with a 'widget' prefix, as in widget.value

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to access the value passed unto the widget

```
widget.value
```